# how to generate html to pdf file in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

how to generate html to pdf file in iphone i need this for iBook applicaion

i got html file but here problem is that i can't do paging in webview so i convert html file into pdf then it is working.

if any body knows the send sample code or link

thanks...

Comment: UIWebview is the only solution that any app developer can provide you, check the forum link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316192/convert-html-file-to-pdf-document-in-ios-using-cocoa-touch

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to consider is sending the HTML serverside, process it there using something like the PHP library DomPDF (which does exactly what you ask: convert HTML to PDF), and download the file.

Just an idea, in case you can't find something comparable running directly on the iPhone.