# Report Generation From Core Data

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, core-data, reporting-services

I am developing a Mac OS X Application that is sort of an inventory management system. Now, I essentially need to include a function that generates reports for the client (exportable to PDF).

The user should select the report that he wishes to view and the appropriate multi paged report should be displayed and available for export/print.

Now in Windows (VB)..there's a third party software known as CRYSTAL REPORTS..that makes it really easy to do so. So, is there such a alternative for Cocoa?

And if not, how do I go about generating the reports from core data that would be multi-paged??

Answer (score 2):

You can easly generate PDF files from HTML in Cocoa - read other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316192/convert-html-file-to-pdf-document-in-ios-using-cocoa-touch) on stackoverflow. Also I recommend to use [GRMustache](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache) for HTML templates.

Comment: Personally I've made my own lightweight XSL-FO parser which generates PDF files directly - one week of hard work and it's working :) I'm going to make it opensource, but not yet… :(