# Convert PDF to HTML in ios?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, pdf

***To Do*** : Convert pdf file to HTML file

For Eg: The pdf file in link below

http://www.inkwelleditorial.com/pdfSample.pdf

should be converted to HTML file.

***Study*** : I googled  and found out few ways to convert HTML to PDF like

1. [Convert html file to PDF Document in iOS using Cocoa-Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316192/convert-html-file-to-pdf-document-in-ios-using-cocoa-touch)
2. [Creating a PDF with iOS](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=160)
3. [Generating PDF Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html)

but could not get any way to do vice versa ie convert  pdf to HTML.

Is there any library available in objective C for above purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I dont think there is a reliable way to keep the formatting (and neither for get all text.)

you'd be better off to display and search the pdf using pspdfkit